# Change paid text in admin panel order details page

Tags: admin

I used this code:

`add_filter('gettext', 'change_text', 20, 3);
function change_text($translated_text, $text, $domain)
{
switch ($translated_text) {

    case 'Paid on %1$s @ %2$s':

        $translated_text = __('Placed on %1$s @ %2$s', 'woocommerce');
        break;

}

return $translated_text;

}`

but It doesn't work for other languages that is not English. Obviously I have translated the text Paid on with the text in my language but It seems not work.

How can I adapt the code for my language (Italian)?
Thank you.